# Type of event dispatched when the user double-clicks the map

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, events

I am currently working with a drawing tool for the ESRI Flex API, and every time I double-click the mouse a map service will perform a measurement and display the length of the line that I am drawing.

I want to mimic this double-click manually by dispatching a MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, but the map service is not listening to this default Flex event. I suspect that the API has created a custom MapMouseEvent or something like it that is being dispatched when a user double-clicks the mouse.

Does anyone know which event is being dispatched when I double-click the mouse on the map?

Comment: Do you mean clicking twice, or clicking both the right and left buttons?

Comment: Clicking twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with the API a bit, I found a solution.  One thing I learned is that even custom events need to listen to the built-in Flash events (e.g. MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK) in order to dispatch their own events.

The Flex API actually dispatches a number of events when a double-click is fired, including a `MapMouseEvent.MAP_CLICK`, `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN`, `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP`, and `MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK` events (in that order).  The MapMouseEvent is a crucial step in the series - it seems like the draw tool will listen for this event to be dispatched before listening for other mouse events (like a double-click).

Answer (score 1):

You should get the effect you want if you add your MouseEvent to the map and disable whatever event is firing that is interfering. I would guess that the problem is that the event for double-click zooming is firing. You can disable it by using the map's doubleClickZoomEnabled property.

If your problem is that you want to add a graphic to the screen that has special functionality and otherwise you'd like double clicking to perform as usual then this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089265/set-a-double-click-event-without-disabling-default-mouseup-mousedown-behavior

should be sufficient to fix that problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know which event is being
>   dispatched when I double-click the
>   mouse on the map?

Multiple events are dispatched, including the standard DOUBLE_CLICK.  Among the Flex API samples there is an "Events" example which you can play with to see this:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html?sample=EventBasics